# Select in MySQL stored procedure not returning values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have a stored procedure, shown below, which I created to add dollar sales to a table (WeeklySales) which currently stores only unit sales. The cursor operates on on the WeeklySales table. The pricing data is stored in the Pricing table. The Pricing table actually contains changes in prices. The effective date for a price change is stored in Pricing.effectiveDate, so I have to find the pricing which was effective for the week in which the unit was sold (which is stored in WeeklySales.weekStart).

The problem I'm having is that the first select after the IF doesn't return anything. I've confirmed that this select does return a value when I run it outside of the procedure using the values which it would be called with inside the procedure. I'm not sure what's wrong here, but I'm guessing maybe this has to do with the fact that the this select is operating on a table which is different from the cursor? Anyone know? Is there a better way to do this?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `createWeeklyPricing` (IN startDate DATE, IN endDate DATE)  
BEGIN
--
-- Populate the proceeds column using the Pricing table
DECLARE product VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE weekStart DATE;
DECLARE units, done INT;
DECLARE proceeds DECIMAL(6,2);
DECLARE effectiveDate DATE;
DECLARE currentRow CURSOR FOR SELECT `weekStart`, `product`, `units` FROM `WeeklySales` WHERE `weekStart` >= startDate AND `weekStart` <= endDate;  
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;  
OPEN currentRow;  
SET done = 0;  
WHILE done = 0 DO  
    FETCH currentRow INTO weekStart, product, units;
    IF done = 0 THEN  
        SELECT MAX(`effectiveDate`) FROM `Pricing` WHERE `effectiveDate` <= weekStart AND `product` = product INTO effectiveDate;
        SELECT `proceeds` FROM `Pricing` WHERE `effectiveDate` = effectiveDate AND `product` = product INTO proceeds;
        UPDATE `WeeklySales` SET `proceeds` = units * proceeds WHERE `weekStart` = weekStart AND `product` = product;
    END IF;
END WHILE;  
CLOSE currentRow;

END//
```

Comment: can you "echo" the select, create a table with one field (text) and insert into it the `CONCAT('SELECT MAX(`effectiveDate`) FROM `Pricing` WHERE `effectiveDate` <=',weekStart,' AND `product` = product INTO ',effectiveDate,';')`

Comment: I've written the effectiveDate variable into a table, and confirmed that it's null. I've also written the weekStart and product variables to a table to confirm that they're the correct values. I've even tried hard coding weekStart and product in the problem select. effectiveDate always comes back as NULL, but ONLY in the stored procedure. If I  type the select into MySQL using the same hard coded values as in the stored procedure case I get the expected value.

Comment: do you run the SP on the same DB as the where you run the queries directly?

Comment: Yes. I added a USE `sales` line to the SP to make sure.

Comment: I also tried hard coding a value in the UPDATE statement just before the end of the IF to make sure the IF is executing and I am writing to the correct table.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure? What about a single SQL statement? (I assure you it would be possible)

Answer (score 0):

echo (select) weekstart before the if statement...

If it returns null change the select FROM `WeeklySales` WHERE `weekStart` between startDate AND endDate

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `INTO` before `FROM` and variable needs `'@'` sign

change it to

```
SELECT MAX(`effectiveDate`) INTO @effectiveDate FROM `Pricing` WHERE `effectiveDate` <= weekStart AND `product` = product ;
```

hope this helps

Comment: This had no effect. effectiveDate is still NULL.

Comment: whats the datatype of effectiveData ? is it date or DateTime? just give it a look

Answer (score 0):

This is because your variable name is overwriting your column name:

You have a variable named 'effectiveDate'

You have a column named 'effectiveDate'

```
SELECT MAX(`effectiveDate`) ...
```

Is MAX-ing the *variable* effectiveDate, not the *column*

Try naming the variable **maxEffectiveDate**

Beware that variables are case insensitive. This happened to me when i tried to select column **IsBackUp** into variable **isBackUp**  (notice the i).